# Tree like structure in views

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type in which I have following fields

Title, year, and report type. I create a block using **BEF** for exposed report type. which is working fine

Now I want to show results as

```
- 2014 
    --Title1
    -- Title2
+ 2013 
     --Title 2013 
     --- Title 2013 1
```

and so on

When i click on + icon result will expand.

Can we do this using views or I have to right custom code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at the [Views tree](https://www.drupal.org/node/1493366) module, to see how well it would fit your needs. Here is a quote about the module (from its project page):

> ... provides a tree-based style plugin for Views.
>
> It is based off of the list style. Although it generates a nested view, there is still only a single query run for the view making it quite performant.

Comment: while implementing this is is giving me internal error.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to include this comment, and also include some copy-paste of the relevant part of the error messages, ok?